# A tree structure recursive algorithm with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I constructed several arrays using the "previous" array, following this rule :

```
D = 500
eta = 10
T = 4

D1 = np.array([D-eta, D+eta])
D2 = np.array([[D1-eta], [D1+eta]], dtype=object)
D3 = np.array([[D2-eta], [D2+eta]], dtype=object)
D4 = np.array([[D3-eta], [D3+eta]], dtype=object)
D5 = np.array([[D4-eta], [D4+eta]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to create Ds area more efficiently, using T value. But before I would like to fully unzip each D area.

For instance, for D2, output is :

[[[480 500]]

[[500 520]]]

and I would like to get :

[480, 500, 500, 520]

Do you know how the extract simply the results ?

By the way I would like to use these arrays for a backward algorithm, for instance at t = 4, for Dt = 480, I would like to to use the mean value of 490 and 470...

Thanks all in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Dn will end up having a great deal of duplicated values.  Perhaps we could help more with more background on the problem you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know how the extract simply the results?

Use [np.ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). Check your output with `print(np.ravel(D2))`

Answer (score 0):

The function `np.hstack` allows you to stack the arrays. I'll then go for something like this:

```py
Dt = np.array(D)
for i in range(T):
    Dt = np.hstack([Dt - eta, Dt + eta])
```